# How do I stop backend execution in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The process takes a long time because it executes a database query. I want to start a new process in between on a button click. For example I want to logout with a button click. How can we tackle this problem?

Comment: you can make the execution of the method which consists of query, asynchronous

Comment: if executing take too long, check your sql query. could be that is badly writen.

Comment: logout button event remains in queue